# Writing a server application that Pushes to clients (TCP)

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, client-server, push

I'm writing a client-server application and one of the requirements is the Server, upon receiving an update from one of the clients, be able to Push out new data to all the other clients. This is a C++ (Qt) application meant to run on Linux (both client and server), but I'm more looking for high-level conceptual ideas of how this should work (though low-level thoughts are good, too).

#### Server:

It needs to (among its other duties) keep a socket open listening for incoming packets from potentially *n* different clients, presumably on a background thread (I haven't written much in terms of socket code other than some rinky-dink examples in school). Upon getting this data from a client, it processes it and then spits it out to all its clients, right?

Of course, I'm not sure how it actually does this. I'm guessing this means it has to keep persistent connections with every single client (at least the active clients), but I don't understand even conceptually how to maintain this connection (or the list of these connections).

So, how should I approach this?

Comment: It is best to think of TCP connections as streams of data, not *packets*.

Answer (score 4):

In general when you have multiple clients, there are a few ways to handle this.

First of all, in TCP, when a client connects to you they're placed into a queue until they can be serviced. This is a given, you don't need to do anything except call the `accept` system call to receive a new client. Once the client is recieved, you'll be given a socket which you use to read and write. Who reads / writes first is entirely dependent on your protocol, but both sides need to know the protocol (which is up to you to define).

Once you've got the socket, you can do a few things. In a simple case, you just read some data, process it, write back to the socket, close the socket, and serve the next client. Unfortunately this means you can only serve one client at a time, thus no "push" updates are possible. Another strategy is to keep a list of all the open sockets. Any "updates" simply iterate over the list and write to each socket. This may present a problem though because it *only* allows push updates (if a client sent a request, who would be watching for it?)

The more advanced approach is to assign one thread to each socket. In this scenario, each time a socket is created, you spin up a new thread whose whole purpose is to serve exactly one client. This cuts down on latency and utilizes multiple cores (if available), but is far more difficult to program. Also if you have 10,000 clients connecting, that's 10,000 threads which gets to be too much. Pushing an update to a single client (in this scenario) is very simple (a thread just writes to its respective socket). Pushing to all of them at once is a little more tricky (requires either a thread event or a producer / consumer queue, neither of which are very fun to implement)

There are, of course, a million other ways to handle this (one *process* per client, a thread pool, a load-balancing proxy, you name it). Suffice it to say there's no way to cover all of these in one answer. I hope this answers your basic questions, let me know if you need me to clarify anything. It's a very large subject. However if I might make a suggestion, handling multiple clients is a wheel that has been re-invented a million times. There are very good libraries out there that are far more efficient and programmer-friendly than raw socket IO. I suggest [libevent](http://libevent.org/), which turns network requests into an event-driven paradigm (much more like GUI programming, which might be nice for you), and is incredibly efficient.

Comment: [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html) is another very well written and easy to use socket library.

Comment: Good suggestion, if the OP is already comfortable with Boost that may be an easier option.

Comment: @Chris so basically I'm going to need to maintain a "keep-alive" socket to every single client for pushing new data, and also have some way (a secondary socket/port) for listening for incoming connections from the clients?

Comment: It's not a "keep-alive" socket, it's a socket. It's your direct line to the client. And yes, the incoming queue also happens to be a socket. But rest assured that even in the simplest scenario, you'd still have at least two sockets in play.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, I think you need to keep an infinite loop going, (at least until the program terminates) that answers a connection request from your clients. It would be best to add them to a array of some sort. Use an event to see when a new client is added to that array, and wait for one of them to give data. Then you do what you have to do with that data and spit it back.